# Dropzone добавление изображений в БД

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, pdo, dropzone

Не добавляются данные в таблицу image

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit']) ){ 
            $adres=$_POST['adres'];
            $city=$_POST['city'];
                
            $insert="INSERT INTO room (id_city,id_user,adres) values ('$city','$id_user','$adres')";
        
                if ( mysqli_query($con, $insert)){

                   } 

    }
                                                
}
?>
```

Это скрипт не выполняется. Наверное, из-за того что после загрузки изображения в dropzone $_FILES очищается. Как исправить?

```
<?php 

if(isset($_POST['submit']) && !empty($_FILES)){ 
 
    $uploadDir = "images/"; 
    $fileName = basename($_FILES['file']['name']); 
    $uploadFilePath = $uploadDir.$fileName; 

    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $uploadFilePath)){ 
     
        $sql = "INSERT INTO images (id_room, name_image) VALUES ('".$id_room."', '".$fileName."')"; 
        $insert = $con->query($sql);
    } 
}       
?>
```

Comment: Используйте функцию print_r($_FILES)  чтобы после нажатия кнопки submit вывелся суперглобальный массив, посмотреть что находится у него внутри и где возникает ошибка. Или вы можете использовать функцию var_dump($ваш массив) которая имеет схожий принцип работы. Напишите вариант что вам вывел PHP. Также очень сильно рекомендую использовать эти функции при разработке ПРЕЖДЕ чем что-то вносить в БД. Так и время сэкономите и сразу 100% обратная связь о поступаемых данных.

Comment: @Eric7777777 выводит пустой массив. Если убрать $_POST['submit']) и указать значение у id_room то изображения добавятся в БД. У меня dropzone.js сразу загружает картинки на сервер. Есть например такой чтобы по кнопке загружать?

Comment: Очень не рекомендую использовать загрузку сразу в БД. Вам туда могут кинуть огромное количество файлов (вирусных) не имеющих разрешение фотографий, какие проверки у вас стоят перед загрузкой изображений на сервер? Испоьзование Dropzone не спасет вам от подмены файлов. Давайте начнем по порядку, опишите что вы хотите получить в итоге? Пользователи загружают фотографии, вы хотите сохранить их имена и id ? Опишите логику.

Comment: @Eric7777777 Пользователь вводит данные о квартире они вставляются в таблицу room, достаём последний id из таблицы room и добавляем картинки в таблицу image зная id_room